# Does Mistral-7B-Instruct use RLHF?

Tags: nlp, large-language-model

In the paper it says

> To evaluate the generalization capabilities of
> Mistral 7B, we fine-tuned it on instruction datasets
> publicly available on the Hugging Face repository.
> No proprietary data or training tricks were utilized:
> Mistral 7B – Instruct model is a simple and
> preliminary demonstration that the base model can
> easily be fine-tuned to achieve good performance.

However they don't specify if they used RLHF or not.